# Line Break in Button?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a button that is made using anchor tags and display:block; (so the entire button in cickable)

I want to add a linebreak in the button (for styling purposes) and am achieving this through the display:block; property. The problem is that the part of the button that the display:block; property is assigned becomes unclickable.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
   <span class="top">Connected To</span>
   <span class="bottom">Relationships</span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
 a{
      display:block;
      padding:5px 20px;
    }
    .top{
      display:block;
      font-size:15px;
    }
    .bottom{
      font-size:25px;
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this code is perhaps more complicated than it needs to be, [it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/z49c7/). Perhaps your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I am using cufon for the fonts, would that have any impact?

Comment: @ShahmeerNavid: Possibly. You should post the *exact* setup you have (preferably as a JSfiddle), otherwise it's hard to see how people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any kind of weird line-height setting that you may have applied with the cufon style?